# python subprocess non-blocking and returning output

Tags: python, subprocess

I know this has been asked a lot of times but I've yet to find a proper way of doing this. If I want to run a local command the docs say I have to use subprocess as it's replacing all other methods such as os.system/peopen etc.

If I call `subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` in my program and the command is for example a openvpn directive which connects my computer to a VPN the process will hang indefinitely since openvpn returns it's output ending with a new line but hangs in there while connected and so does my program (frozen).

Some say I should remove the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` which indeed works in a non-blocking way but then everything gets printed to the console instead of me having some sort of control over the output (maybe I dont want to print it).

So is there some sort of proper way of doing this, an example maybe of executing commands in a non-blocking way and also having control over the output.?

Comment: Does using communicate() help? http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Answer (score 0):

If you specify stdout=PIPE, then your subprocess will write to the pipe and hang when the pipe buffer is full.  The python program shoudn't hang - Popen is asynchronous which is why `Popen.wait()` can be called later to wait for the subprocess to exit.  Read from `Popen.stdout` in order to keep the subprocess happy, and print, discard, or process the output as you see fit.

Answer (score -1):

Consider running your process within a terminal. For example,

```
subprocess.Popen("xterm -e /bin/bash -c '/path/to/openvpn'", shell=True)
```

or even, you could try,

```
import shlex
subprocess.Poen(shlex.split("xterm -e /bin/bash -c '/path/to/openvpn'"), shell=False)
```

Comment: I dont think thats the case for a multi-platform software